# Mono.timeout triggering immediately

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I have not seen this question asked so it might be a really rare situation or maybe I am doing something wrong, but basically I am trying to create a Mono that waits on a message from an MQ JMS message.

```
Mono result = Mono.create(sink -> msgProcessor.registerListener(sink::success, requestId))
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
      .onErrorReturn(msgProcessor.timeout())
      .doFinally(change -> msgProcessors.remove(requestId));
```

So it seems like timeout is always being triggered and the timeout method is executed. Anyone know why?

Comment: What is the result of `registerListener`?

Comment: It is void, it registers a Consumer<Object> and sets a String.

Answer (score 0):

The `create(Consumer<MonoSink<T>> callback)` deals with the signals inside the `Mono` over the `MonoSink<T>` that lets you emit values through `MonoSink.success()`, `MonoSink.success(value)`, `MonoSink.error(throwable)` methods.

In your example, you don't emit any value; thus, `.timeout` is always being triggered.

Since `registerListener` method does not produce any value, you should replace `Mono.create` with `Mono.fromRunnable` like this:

```java
Mono.fromRunnable(() -> msgProcessor.registerListener(sink::success, requestId))
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```